# Luggage Storage at Szechenyi Baths

Tags: hungary, budapest

I’d like to visit the Szechenyi baths on my last day in Budapest before my evening train departs at 8:30. In order to do this most easily, I’d like to take my luggage with me and store it in a cabin rental. Is there enough space to do this with a full size (22kg) suitcase? Or am I better off storing my goods at the train station for the day and then heading to the baths with a backpack?

Answer (score 13):

The official website of the baths note that the lockers are size "120x30x65 cm", and that larger bags can be stored within the cabin.

Cabins are actually personal changing rooms that you get assigned to, and you open with a wristband so it is secure. As stated on their [website](http://szechenyispabaths.com/can-you-leave-the-bag-in-the-cabin-in-szechenyi-baths/)

> "The size of the cabin can easily hold a standard suitcase or a
>   backpacker style bigger backpack"

Here's a photo so you can fully appreciate how big the cabins are!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can store it there, it will also be cheaper too since you will probably get a locker at the bath for your valuble items anyway, so no need to duplicate!